# How to make a div of iframe float on top of another div of iframe that should be the background of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I read many related questions but my case seems a little bit different that none of those really work for me.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a floating radio player that play nonstop music throughout my blog. I'm using iframe to put my blog as the background of the whole page, then another iframe for the radio player that float on top the previous iframe.

I guess the reason that all methods I found couldn't work is because the property of my iframe:

```
<iframe src="my blog address" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="120%" width="120%"></iframe>
```

Following is what the entire page look like(I need the radio player to float on the top):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div id="radio_player">
<iframe src="http://douban.fm/partner/baidu/doubanradio" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>


<div id="blog_background">

<iframe src="http://swotong.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="120%" width="120%"></iframe>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm quite new to coding and posting questions here, thanks for any help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `z-index:1` to the frame you want on top.

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/)

you have to use a `position` property for this to work.

[position attributes from css3.com](http://www.css3.com/css-position/)

Comment: You are so right, I didn't use position property. It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can choose it as best answer